# vimscript get number of first and last visible line

Tags: vim

I know I can go to the first and last visible line of current buffer with H and L respectively. But how I can pass the line numbers to variables ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let topline = line("w0")
let botline = line("w$")
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but if nothing else, you can use `H` and `L` to move there and ``` `` ``` to get back and get. Something like

```
norm 'H'
let top=line('.')
norm '``L'
let bottom=line('.')
norm '``'
```

or you can use `getpos()` to store and `setpos()` to restore the position, but I am not sure you can avoid destroying the previous position mark (the `:keepmarks` command should do that, but it's documentation says it only works in some special case).